# How to remove empty space in tabs

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, css, tabs

I just set up two custom tabs ["Technical Data" and "More Info"] for my site with the help of this [link](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:9P7iaN_2oJMJ:www.ddcantt.in/2015/06/how-to-add-custom-additional-tab-for-my.html%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=in) and using the following codes.

Added the following Blocks after Description block in `/app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/layout`

technicaldata block

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.technicaldata" as="technical" template="catalog/product/view/technicaldata.phtml">
                <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Technical Data</value></action>
</block>
```

moreinfo block

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.moreinfo" as="moreinfo" template="catalog/product/view/moreinfo.phtml">
                    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>More Info</value></action>
</block>
```

Added the following PHTML files in

`/app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/template/catalog/product/view`

technicaldata.phtml

```
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php if ($_product->gettechnicaldata()):?>
                <div class="short-technicaldata">
                    <div class="std"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->gettechnicaldata()), 'technicaldata') ?></div>
                </div>
            <?php endif;?>
```

moreinfo.phtml

```
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php if ($_product->getmoreinfo()):?>
                <div class="short-moreinfo">
                    <div class="std"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getmoreinfo()), 'moreinfo') ?></div>
                </div>
            <?php endif;?>
```

Added technicaldata and moreinfo as an attribute and then assigned it to the product.

Now on the front end i am getting an empty space before my data is displayed. However this empty space shows up only in my Technical Data tab and not on More Info tab. How can i remove this empty space and what was my mistake?

In the Technical data tab i have inserted a table using the `<div class="table wrapper">` to make my table responsive whereas in More Info tab i have just entered a single line of data giving the brands dealt.

Comment: Update - Normal text is displayed properly however as soon as i add a table empty space is displayed before the actual table. This issue is faced even after removing the table wrapper div.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the CSS for [collapsing](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/collapsing-margins/) margins.

A possible workaround is to add a small `padding-top` value to the wrapping div.